# Ionic - Wrong tab active after changing tabs template

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic and I am stuck in one place because I want to change my default tabs layout to other one.
When I change to state where I reload my tabs layout, in new layout there is always selected second one, no matter what I do... I want first tab to be selected.

Here is plnkr. Go to friends, click one and look on tabs at bottom. Second one is active :(

`$ionicTabsDelegate` is not working (Or I have done something wrong)

http://plnkr.co/edit/AGNLaMqY6Hzbm5SVcgwI

Do you have any ideas why it's happening?